# Show pie chart side by side

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

Using [angularjs-nvd3-directives](https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives) how to show two (or more) pie charts side by side (instead of one under another)? Solutions should be declarative (ie. without using `<table>`).

Here is example http://plnkr.co/edit/A5B47PNyzBiS5oj0L8bp?p=preview.

```
<nvd3-pie-chart
    data="exampleDataPieChart"
    id="toolTipExample1"
    x="xFunction()"
    y="yFunction()"
    width="250"
    tooltips="true">
</nvd3-pie-chart>

<nvd3-pie-chart
    data="exampleDataPieChart"
    id="toolTipExample2"
    x="xFunction()"
    y="yFunction()"
    width="250"
    tooltips="true">
</nvd3-pie-chart>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout this modification of your plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wrozi31bys3W1ss8PsFC?p=preview)

The idea is that you can and sometimes MUST set styles to custom directives

Comment: capturing the core of the answer: nvd3-pie-chart style="display:inline-block"